# Please [doanswer] if you want to burninate this tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

I feel like the [doanswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/doanswer) tag isn't really helpful in finding a question, and we do generally like to assume that you would like an answer when you post on this site.

Yes, there is `doAnswer` in Java, but the tag can still be abused quite easily. And anyway, it doesn't help us find those questions, and we don't really create tags for each programming statement anyway.

This tag has only **4** questions, of which

- **4** could live without the tag, and have other tags
- **3** are actually on-topic for that tag
- **1** uses the tag simply to indicate they want an answer
- **1** is closed as off-topic
- All the on-topic questions are over **3** years old
- The highest scoring questions have a score of just **1**

Also,

- There is no usage guidance or tag wiki for this tag
- I don't beleive there is anyone watching or following this tag

So should we burninate it?

Comment: Given the volume I don't really think a full burniate is required. Just delete the tag from the 4 questions and the tag will die of it's own accord in, I think, 24 hours.

Comment: 75% of the questions using the tag properly is actually not bad at all as tags go, there are plenty that are far worse.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I was just suggesting this :)

Comment: @ErikA the fact that worse tags exist is no argument against removing other bad tags ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no point in burninating this tag and *certainly* not in blacklisting it. We don't burninate tags because they're unpopular.

It's a perfectly fine tag for the questions where it is properly used. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64689732/is-there-someone-that-knows-what-is-kryptocrons) was just a garbage question that was mistagged 6 ways from Sunday. Don't blame the tag. The root problem has now been addressed.

Comment: I understand. Just a suggestion, but thanks! I do think that this tag is a bit ambiguous but I think we should edit the tag wiki instead of burninating the entire tag. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone can suggest an edit to a tag wiki. (Hint, hint) :-)